# Krita - How to disable the transform tool's behavior that changes the opacity/layer ordering of the layer being transformed?

Tags: krita

One of the most frustrating features of Krita is how it brings the layer you're transforming to the top of the render/preview stack, making it render in front of everything else, including guides.

This is not helpful and "ease-of-use" at all, as it can make it really difficult to see the guide.

For example, in the preview below, the layer being transformed is showing above the guide.

I can't seem to find the setting where this can be configured. Is there a way to disable this behavior? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.  When I try, the guides are still visible through the object being transformed, as are the objects underneath. [See example here](https://imgur.com/a/rxcTuKz). What version of Krita are you using?  I'm using version 4.0.3.

Comment: @BillyKerr, you do replicate a version of the problem. Notice that the pink layer gets rendered behind the yellow layer when you start transforming. Although yes, the guides remain on top. Ideally I'd like the feature to behave similar to how it does in Photoshop as it is much more usable like that. I'm using Krita 4.2.5.

Comment: There will be some improvements to the way transform tool is handled on canvas, In the newer version of Krita i.e. version 5 this will solved.

Comment: I love the way you described this problem! I've been having the same issue but I noticed it seems localized to the layer directly above the one being transformed while layers above those two remain visible. So I create a layer of neutral value just above the one being transformed so it gets hidden and I can see the other layers I'm trying to comply the transform to.